# Is it an acceptable etiquette to establish a connection with the CEO of a small company after having short-listed by his HR?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process, hiring

So I was short-listed by the HR of a french company and whose CEO is also french. The interview is the day after today.

Upon looking up the satellite data gathering system the company relies on, I am very tempted to drop the CEO an email to inquire about the technology and the more intricate details with which the satellite system plays a role in data gathering.

The CEO comes from a technical background as I do.  I have visited the profile of the CEO and he has checked mine out too.

Is it a good idea to establish contact at this point? Would I come across as a potential competitor? What are off limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to establish contact at this point?

Yes, why not make an introduction?  Let the CEO know what position your applying for, and keep the email fairly brief.

> Would I come across as a potential competitor?

I think if you dig too hard for the technical details of their operation *you could be viewed more as a competitor* versus a candidate.  I would avoid this if I were you.

> What are off limits?

This one is a little tough.  I would stick to being **professional**, *general* questions about the company and the culture **are good**, and maybe dig deeper into the *business model*.

I would avoid any type of compensation questions.